# Нажатие клавиш в браузере (selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium, button

Использую `Selenium` для прохождения регистрации на сайте, имеется кнопка(вот вся информация по ней):

```
<a class="nav-link biz-btn-solid" href="/signup">Регистрация</a>
```

За что тут ухватиться?
 `ClassName` почему-то не работает:

```
IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("nav-link biz-btn-solid"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium из коробки НЕ умеет работать с `computed propertys` (то есть когда указывается несколько значений в некоем проперти, в даном случае с `computed class`). Но его можно научить.

Например, даный код:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".class1Name.class2Name"));
```

ищет по двум значениям класса. Если расширить `By` методом `ComputedClass(string class)`, сделать риплейс всех пробелов на точки и потом внутри возвратить даный селектор -- будет возможность искать и по компьютед классам. Это один из методов реализации, но не единственный!

Например, можно искать по такому xpath: `//a[contains(@class, 'class1Name') and contains(@class, 'class2Name')]`

Так же настоятельно советую научится использовать xpath для поиска элементов. Он очень очень очень... Ну прям **ОЧЕНЬ** удобный. Им можно найти ВСЕ. Обожаю им пользоватся.

---

В даном случае должно быть что-то вроде:

```
IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/signup'));
```

и главное -- малая вероятность что линк на эту страницу изменится. А значит... А значит что вероятность что нечаянно поламается тест -- минимальная.

Comment: А что если кнопка такая? '<input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" class="biz-btn-solid">'

Comment: @ПростоКодер можно по валью кнопки искать(но это плохой вариант, а если пользователь изменит язык? Тест начнет ломатся), можно Css селектор подобрать хороший, можно подобрать xpath селектор хороший. Не забывай, что реально хороший селектор можно подобрать только смотря на полный код страници, но никак не на код одного элемета :) А плохой селектор я тебе писать не хочу. Изучай более глубоко Xpath и/или CssSelector и для тебя не проблема будет подобрать правильный селектор на любой элемент. Остальными селекторами которыми предлогает пользоватся селениум пользоватся советую по минимуму.

Comment: Ладно, большое спасибо и на этом)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй убрать пробел из названия класса и оставить только часть. У меня где-то такое работало.
   IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("nav-link"));

Comment: Ну почти) Класс "nav-link" имеет другая кнопка(

Comment: Может быть убрать пробел?Или вместо него что-то поставить?

Comment: Нет не работет(

Comment: Если кнопка такая: **<input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" class="biz-btn-solid">**, то такой код?: ' IWebElement button2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@type, 'submit' "));'